# Oracle join query in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the sample oracle query i need to be changed to SQLSERVER 2008.Basically it gets the description from table2 for the scode and if there is no or null description using 'case' it is made to 'unknown'. How to do.

```
      select a.scode,b.description,a.amt,a.purid 
       from
      (select scode,ISNULL(SUM(AMOUNT),0) AS AMT,count(pur_ID)
       from table1
       where scode is not null 
       group by scode)A, table2 B  WHERE  A.SOURCE_CODE =+B.SOURCE
```

Comment: Ugh... this was bad in Oracle too. Oracle still allows the older =+ join syntax, but that doesn't mean it's recommended or good practice. The best-practice way to write this query in Oracle would also work in Sql Server _without modification_.

Comment: Used left join but gives more rows than the rows in the table A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (Please note I am joining with `=`):

```
Select A.Scode, A.Amt, A.Counts, IsNull(B.Description, 'Unknown') Descripton
From (
      select Scode, SOURCE_CODE, Isnull(sum(amount),0) as Amt, count(pur_ID) Counts
      from table1 
      where scode is not null 
      group by scode, SOURCE_CODE
    ) A left join  table2 B on A.SOURCE_CODE = B.SOURCE
```

**Edit as per comments**:

```
Select A.Scode, Isnull(sum(A.amount),0) as Amt, 
      count(A.pur_ID) Counts, IsNull(Max(B.description), 'Unknown') description
From Table1 A Left Join Table2 B
        On A.SOURCE_CODE = B.SOURCE
Where A.Scode is not null 
Group by A.Scode
```

Comment: This works perfectly but there is more than one description in table2 and only the first one is needed.

Comment: Is `SOURCE` having duplicate data in Table2?

Comment: It should be okay but note i am using Max(description) to eliminate duplicates from Table2

Comment: It seems working but the purid and amt is being added the times number of accurences of the Sourcecode.